# Save document without background in Photoshop to .pdf with really small size

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop

I have really small .pdf file (300 Kb) consists of 5 pages of documents without background. I received it from someone. I open it in Photoshop to make some edits and try to save it. Even if I don't do any edits and save only one page it would weight above 1 Mb. My question is how can I save it in Photoshop in size compared to original (60 Kb per page)?

Comment: Photoshop is for images, a PDF file is a document.  They are different things.  You are essentially opening up a Word Document in a Photo Editor.  Apples and Oranges.

Comment: But I can open pdf in photoshop and make some edits. I can also save it as .pdf. But why does it bloat size so much and how may I keep size similar to original?

Comment: Color conversion, image compression, downsampling, and a relatively low image resolution can all wildly change the file size. Most PDFs are saved with a "Good enough for web content" Preset.  Photoshop defaults to "We will save it as full size."  Because once you compress and downsample, it's VERY hard to uncompress and upsample an image to get it back to perfect.   You may wish to play around with the Presets.  More information can be found here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-pdf-files.html